# Meaning of あすは天気だと思う

Tags: meaning

In my dictionary app I found this as an example phrase:

> あすは天気だと思う

They say it means:

> I hope it'll be fine tomorrow.

Is this a correct Japanese sentence at all? And does it mean what they say it means? To me it means "there is weather"

「あす」is 「明日」, I can get that「思う」means "I hope" instead of "I think", but I really don't get the rest at all. Is it that 「天気だ」means "the weather is/will be nice" in this context, and "it'll be fine" refers to the weather? As in, taken from a conversation of people already talking about the weather.

Comment: Did the dictionary only list "weather" as the meaning of 天気?

Comment: `2. fair weather; fine weather 今日が天気ならいいのに。I wish it were fine today.` ([Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A4%A9%E6%B0%97))

Comment: @Leebo Yes I did find that later but it wasn't enough to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, both you and your dictionary app are incorrect. あすは天気だと思う means "I think it'll be fine tomorrow".

- 思う is "think", not "hope".
- 天気 is not just a noun meaning "weather", but it's also a noun (no-adjective) that means "fine (weather)". That is, 今日は天気です means "It's fine today" rather than "It's weather today". It's hard to imagine a dictionary that doesn't explain this definition, so please recheck your dictionary.

Comment: Out of context I understood "*it'll be fine tomorrow*" as "*things will be OK tomorrow*". But when I read it as "*the weather will be fine tomorrow*", the sentence makes sense. I guess my biggest misunderstanding was with the English sentence haha